# reactjs Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am pretty sure i am returning an object and have used asyn and await on the promise within my action file. but this still keeps returing the error `redux.js:205 Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions`

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-nash-wdcjf?fontsize=14

my action file is returning an object

```
import axios from "axios";

export const LOAD_URL_STATUS = "LOAD_URL_STATUS";

export async function loadUrlStatus(url) {
  const request = await axios
    .get(url)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.status);
      return response.status;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("Looks like there was a problem: \n", error);
    });
  console.log(request);
  console.log(LOAD_URL_STATUS);
  return {
    type: LOAD_URL_STATUS,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

it fails when calling this action in componenDidMount `this.props.loadUrlStatus(url);`

component

```
import React from 'react';
import TrafficLight from '../TrafficLight';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {loadUrlStatus} from "../../actions";
//import {withPolling} from "../Polling";
//import Polling from "../Polling/polling";
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class TrafficLightContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      redOn: true,
      yellowOn: false,
      greenOn: false,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
console.log("componentDidMount")
const {pollingAction, duration, url} = this.props
    //withPolling(this.props.loadUrlStatus(this.props.url),1)
    /*
    const {pollingAction, duration, url} = this.props
    this.dataPolling = setInterval(
                    () => {
                        this.props.loadUrlStatus(url);
                    },
                    10000);
*/
this.props.loadUrlStatus(url);
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
                clearInterval(this.dataPolling);
            }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <TrafficLight
        Size={100}
        onRedClick={() => this.setState({ redOn: !this.state.redOn })}
        onGreenClick={() => this.setState({ greenOn: !this.state.greenOn })}
        RedOn={this.state.redOn}
        GreenOn={this.state.greenOn}
      />
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    ...state
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
        loadUrlStatus
    },
    dispatch
  );
};

export default (
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TrafficLightContainer));
```

index

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './configureStore'

const store = configureStore();

const renderApp = () =>
  render(
        <Provider store={store}>
                <App />
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root')
  );



if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./App', renderApp)
}

renderApp();

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Post relevant code in the question . Questions should be self contained. We shouldn't have to go off site just to do an initial review of the problem. Demos are great, but only as support for what actually exists in the question itself

Comment: @shorif2000 I don;t see any actions. actions\index.js is empty...

Comment: @Fyodor i have updated the sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `loadUrlStatus` is async function, so it returns not object, but Promise, and object inside it promise.

To correct this, modify `loadUrlStatus` so it return another function. As you already applied thunk middleware during store creation, such function will be called inside redux. (You can see samples of async functions [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#motivation))

```
export function  loadUrlStatus(url) {
    // Immediately return another function, which will accept dispatch as first argument. It will be called inside Redux by thunk middleware
    return async function (dispatch) {
        const request = await axios
            .get(url)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.status);
                return response.status;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("Looks like there was a problem: \n", error);
            });
            console.log(request);
            console.log(LOAD_URL_STATUS);
            dispatch ({
                type: LOAD_URL_STATUS,
                payload: request
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `await` in an action creator, you'll want to return a function from the action creator. Otherwise, return on object. A library like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) will help you do just that.

Your action creator would then look like this:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const LOAD_URL_STATUS = "LOAD_URL_STATUS";

export const loadUrlStatus(url) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const response = await axios(url)

    dispatch({
      type: LOAD_URL_STATUS,
      payload: response.status
    })
  } catch (error) {
    // dispatch error
  }
}
```